# Can't reach containerized service behind nginx container

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I got this architecture and it is **almost** working.

- I can `curl` the service directly and it dispatches the requests to the replicas running behind.
- Also I can curl the `nginx` container.
- Additionally I can run `docker exec -i nginx curl http://articleservice:8080/somemethod` without any issues.

But something seems to be wrong with my config. The nginx and the container are on the same network.

> Architecture:

```
                                             [replica 2]
                                            /
[incoming traffic] -> [nginx] -> [service a]
                                            \
                                             [replica 1]
```

> docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  articleservice:
    image: elps/articleservice:1.1.0.5
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=192.168.178.96
      - MYSQL_DB=catalog
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    networks:
      - webnet     

  nginx-default:
    image: nginx
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet

networks:
  webnet:
```

> **nginx-config**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name example.com;

  location /article {
      proxy_pass http://articleservice:8080/; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Using kubernetes would be a wise choice

Answer (score 1):

Once again, I forgot to add the host in the header.

Solution:

`curl -H 'host: example.com' http://articleservice:8080/somemethod`

Answer (score 0):

You should create a volume in the nginx-default service so it can use the nginx.conf file.

Example:

```
  nginx-default:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
```

Another problem is that if you access the url *example.com/article/someMethod* it will translate to *articleservice:8080/article/someMethod*
To remove the prefix "/article" part you can rewrite it:

```
  location /article {
      proxy_pass http://articleservice:8080/; 
      rewrite ^/article(.*)$ $1 break;
  }
```

Now you can use *curl example.com/article/someMethod* to use the articleService